# Laravel: Multiple SELECTs using UNION - as one query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following query which uses `UNION` and `priority` alias column:

```
SELECT id, name, 4 as priority FROM `topics`
WHERE id IN(17, 18, 19, 20, 21) AND name LIKE 'ge'

UNION

SELECT id, name, 3 as priority FROM `topics`
WHERE id IN(17, 18, 19, 20, 21) AND name LIKE '%ge%'

UNION

SELECT id, name, 2 as priority FROM `topics`
WHERE name LIKE 'ge%'

UNION

SELECT id, name, 1 as priority FROM `topics`
WHERE name LIKE '%ge%'

ORDER BY priority DESC
```

**Is it possible to "translate it" to Laravel's Query Builder, so it remains one query?**

I know I could put all the `SELECT`s in separate variables and then chain them with `->union()` but I'm afraid this will perform 4 queries first, one by one, and finally just combine the results.

Comment: when you run this into sql or mysql how this will perform, this will one by one and combined their result just similar as laravel do. If not how these will perform/run in db?

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel Documentation:

> The query builder also provides a quick way to "union" two queries
>   together:
>
> $first = DB::table('users')->whereNull('first_name');
>
> $users =
>   DB::table('users')->whereNull('last_name')->union($first)->get(); The
>   unionAll method is also available, and has the same method signature
>   as union.

I think, for now, is the only way to unions in Laravel. I think the first query doesn't get the data, because don't add the ->get() chain.

Comment: You are correct. Just building a query will definitely not run it!

Answer (score 1):

Using union in Laravel's query builder does not execute the query. The `union()` method expects a query builder instance to be passed to it or an instance of `Closure`. This is stored in a union array within the builder instance and only when the query is executed does it combine all the component parts.

For example this will only run one query when `get()` is called:

```
DB::table('topics')
    ->whereIn('id', [17,18,19,20,21])
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', 'ge')
    ->union(DB::table('topics')
        ->whereIn('id', [17,18,19,20,21])
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', 'ge%')
    )->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `DB::getQueryLog()` to see what the query actually was. I would like to believe Laravel doesn't execute the query until you call `->get()` or `->first()` upon it.

Comment: @DavidBarker Why the donwvote, my answer was very similiar to the other ones. The query is not executed until you call `get()` on it.